# Как читать файлы в несколько потоков в Linux?

Tags: php, linux

Есть такая задача: лежит 10000 файликов на диске, и их необходимо как можно быстрее переконвертировать, хочется это сделать в много - поточном или процессном подходе 
Какие есть ограничения:

- 1. Мы не должны по 2 раза читать файлик
- 2. Если поток вдруг завис, нужно как то определить что он завис и потушить его, а дескриптор этого файлика освободить для другого потока
- 3. При окончании работы всех потоков нужно проверить чтобы никто не остался висеть в памяти.
     Интересно как к этой задаче подойти более правильно ? можно ответить на словах без кода. Спасибо.
     еще дополню что обработка не разовая, и файлы все время добавляются может 20  файлов в секунду. Размер файлов до 10 мб.

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что если это все написать на с/c++ то даже не нужно будет ничего паралелить. Уже будет быстро.

Comment: Самый простой вариант это использовать что то типа: RabbitMq/Zeromq/Gearman... Для управления процессами можно глянуть: http://supervisord.org/. А вообше скорость упрется в скорость чтения.

Comment: @KoVadim Зависит от сложности обработки, мастерства программиста... Есть вариант когда очень быстрый  код C/C++ будет написан только тогда, когда PHP/Python закончит работу ;)

Comment: @E_p ответ зависит от того, нужно это однократно делать или многократно. Но раз автор пишет о том, что нужно делать быстро, есть подозрение, что нужно многократно.

Но если нужно это сделать однократно, тогда можно смело писать на пхп в один поток и не переживать.

Comment: @itcoder Если файлы как то структурированы/пронумерованы делаете однопоточный конвертер и параметром разруливаете какие файлы берет. Например, если есть номера в названиях запускаете 4 копии и каждая берет файлы со своим остатком от деления номера файла на 4. Вместо номеров из названий можно использовать номера inode (Если доступны). Но если сам процесс обработки быстрый - то вы упретесь не в скорость скрипта, а в скорость диска и никакие потоки не помогут.

Comment: @itcoder Можно вариант `Mike`  не запуская 4 скрипта сделать а в http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php обернуть.Задачу можно решить по разному, зависит от деталей. Если нужен конкретнее ответ уточните вопрос. Как часто надо конвертироовать? Какие файлы? Размер? Как сложна обработка? Будет ли идти запись в БД? ...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, вариант с очередями подойдет, но если так получиться что файлы все время дабавляються например по 10 файлов в секунду,тогда логика такая есть consumer который берет все файлики, разбивает на группы  например по 20 файликов в группе, передает их в очереди с разными ключами, но когда consumer запуститься второй раз, у него не будет метки что файл уже в работе

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | parallel convert {}
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 convert {}
```